# How to manage multiple Firebase Real Time Databases that need to contain duplicate data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase RTDB for my marketplace web application. I created 3 different RTDB to service the 3 multi regions to deliver content the fastest. However, since users have to interact with each other all 3 RTDB have to have exactly the same data. I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to stop the 3 RTDB from updating each other every time new data is uploaded to one (since all 3 continuously update each other).

Not sure how to specify when the 3 RTDB should stop updating each other.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, and the right one depends on your specific scenario and implementation. But a common way is to detect if the data already exists before deciding to write it. If you're about to write the exact same data as exists, you skip writing it and thus break the propagation loop.